# How to Add jQuery cod in wordpress

Tags: jquery

I would like to add this small jQuery code in my wordpress website but no way.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.flex-active-slide').append('<div class="playoverlay"></div>');
});
```

I tried many solution on the web like

Create a js file with and call it with wp_enqueue.

```
<?php wp_enqueue_script("jquery-mycustom-core",'/wp-content/themes/example/mycustom.js', array('jquery'), '1.8.8'); ?>
```

Also i tried put it on the functions.php.

```
//this goes in functions.php near the top
function my_scripts_method() {
// register your script location, dependencies and version
wp_register_script('custom_script',
'/wp-content/themes/example/mycustom.js',
array('jquery'),
'1.0' );
// enqueue the script
wp_enqueue_script('custom_script');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method');
```

Also i trid this :

```
add_action('wp_head', 'add_scripts');
function add_scripts() { ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('.flex-active-slide').append('<div class="playoverlay"></div>');
});
</script>
<?php }
```

And i also inserted directly on the footer and the header but noway.

but when i execute this code on the browser console it work.

Any help please.

---

Thanks Alex For help so here is what i did but still didn't work

**mycustom.js**

```
j(document).ready(function(){
var j = jQuery.noConflict();
j('.flex-active-slide').append('<div class="playoverlay"></div>');
});
```

**header.php**

```
    <?php wp_register_script('myjs',get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/mycustom.js',array('jquery'),false,true);
      wp_enqueue_script('myjs') ?>
```

Comment: Are you sure your Theme calls `wp_head()` and `wp_footer()`?

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
var j = jQuery.noConflict();
```

now everywhere in script JQurey is needed use `j` instead of `$` or `JQuery`
also your enqueue line should be like this:

```
wp_register_script('myjs',get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/my_script.js',array('jquery'),false,true);

wp_enqueue_script('myjs');
```

you can read more [here](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/)

**P.S**: so your updated code should be :

**mycustom.js**

```
  var j = jQuery.noConflict();//this line Must be first line of script

j(document).ready(function(){
   j('.flex-active-slide').append('<div class="playoverlay"></div>');
});
```

**functions.php** //NOt header.php

```
<?php wp_register_script('myjs',get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/mycustom.js',array('jquery'),false,true);
  wp_enqueue_script('myjs') ?>
```

Comment: Thanks Alex i did what u said but stl dont work (see first post updated)

Comment: i added an update to the answer

Comment: hello thanks for the help i did exactly what you said but still cant make it work !